# Changing UIBarButtonItem title looks bad

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

Whenever I tried to change a bar button item's title, if the second title is longer then the first one, the button shows ... in the title, then it gets resized.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has a solution I just discovered:

```
barButtonItem.possibleTitles = Set(["Original title", "Other title", "Third option"])
```

This way it sets the item's size to fit the longest of the possible titles.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution! Lots of people just leave the question. You should also accept your own answer so others know that it's solved.

Comment: I will but it needs a day or two until I can